# Excel time increment in a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Sorry for being not clear on my query .
A1 contains Friday, March 16, 2018 3:06 PM
So from A2 to A15 I want the content in A1 to be same except the time 3:06 PM
On each cell I want to do an increment in the timing 
Such as 3:08 PM, 3:25 PM, 3:27 PM ( note : increment no need to be in a sequential order , I want it to increment without any sequential order ) once I reached the A15 my content should be 
Friday, March 16, 2018 7:00 PM .
3:06 to 7:00 must be an ascending order but no need to be sequential.

Hope it clears everything .
Please guide how to get it done.

Comment: So increment by? 1 sec? 1 min? 1 hr? How many times you want the increment to be?

Comment: ^^All of the above and how many cells? Where are these cells?

Answer (score 1):

Your question wasn't 100% clear to me, but I'll try to answer anyway: In Excel, the "format" and the actual contents of the cell are separate. If Excel doesn't recognize your format as a date format, enter it like this: 2018-03-16 15:06, then change the format later (Format cells -> Date -> choose something appropriate, possibly change it a bit)

Let's say this is in cell A1, and you want 15:06 through 19:00 in column B. In formulas, you add minutes by adding `+TIME(0,1,0)` to the formula (0 hours, 1 minute, 0 seconds). Now you could put `=$A$1` in the first row, `$A$1+TIME(0,1,0)` in the second row, `=$A$1+TIME(0,2,0)` in the next, etc., but that's tedious. (The $ marks assure that the formula will always reference A1, even if you drag it down or copy and paste it elsewhere.)

You can use `ROW()` to get the row number in a formula. In cell B1, this would give us "1", in cell B2, "2", etc. In B1, we wouldn't want to add anything so we don't just do `+TIME(0,ROW(),0)`, but rather subtract one from the row, so it becomes: `=$A$1+TIME(0,ROW()-1,0)`. Then we can just drag down the formula until we've reached 19:00 and we're done.

Comment: I think it was a little harsh for someone to downvote you. Your formula should be =$A$1+TIME(0,ROW()-1,0) without the additional ")"

Comment: Oops, thanks! Fixed in two places. Wonder if that's the reason for the downvote or if I just totally misunderstood the question

Comment: Can the answer you gave be easily adapted in case OP wanted seconds or hours?

Comment: Yeah, TIME() handles that comfortably. E.g., one hour would be TIME(1,0,0), one second would be TIME(0,0,1)

Comment: then +1 for me as I think is helpful despite OP not being specific